# Float left div one over other along with a float right wide div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the layout as shown in the picture. Where multiple smaller divs (A,C,D) are float left and top of each other while bigger Divs (B,D) are float right and top of each o ther[image]

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: jsfiddle.net  please post ur code here

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/SLNBS/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Rwy/) ?

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='left'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class='right'>
    <div class='div1'></div>
    <div class='div2'></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width:460px;    
}

.left{

    width:150px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.left > div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:90px;
    background:brown

}

.right{
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid orange;
    text-align:center    

}

.div1{

    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    background:black

}

.div2{

    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:80px;
    background:yellow

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way. Its quite the same as image/text wrapping. Just copy and paste it then modify how you would like it. :)

```
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
                .bigDiv{
                    float: right;
                    width: 70%;
                    border: 1px solid red;
                    height: 300px;
                }
                .smallDiv{
                    width: 30%;
                    border: 1px solid red;
                    height: 100px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="bigDiv"></div>
            <div class="smallDiv"></div>
            <div class="smallDiv"></div>
            <div class="smallDiv"></div>
            <div class="bigDiv"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML and CSS.

I made this jsFiddle for you with a setup for your layout.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

[Demo](http://tinyurl.com/pw4fmbl)